# Issue with discord.js slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm having an issue with the slash commands; it just sends back "The application did not respond".

I'm not sure but it looks like the bot isn't reading the commands.

I was thinking maybe it's the intents or permissions on discord. The bot has all perms and intents are up to date. Not sure what i did wrong.

```js
const { ChatInputCommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  name: "interactionCreate",
  /**
   *
   * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
   */
  execute(interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
    if (!command) return interaction.reply({
        content: "This command is outdated.",
        ephemeral: false,
      });

    if (command.developer && interaction.user.id !== '268914030528299008')
      return interaction.reply({
        content: "This command is only available to Dev.",
        ephemeral: false,
      });

    command.execute(interaction, client);
  },
};
```

index.js file

```js
const {GatewayIntentBits, Collection, Partials, Client } = require('discord.js');
const {Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages} = GatewayIntentBits
const {User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember } = Partials;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [ Guilds, GuildMessages, GuildMembers ],
  partials: [ User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember ]
});

const { loadEvents } = require('./Handlers/eventHandler');

require('dotenv').config();
client.events = new Collection();
client.commands = new Collection();

loadEvents(client);

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

CommandHandler

```js
async function loadCommands(client) {
    const { loadFiles } = require("../Functions/fileLoader");
    const ascii = require("ascii-table");
    const table = new ascii().setHeading("Commands", "Status");
  
    await client.commands.clear();
  
    let commandsArray = [];
  
    const Files = await loadFiles("Commands");
    Files.forEach((file) => {
      const command = require(file);
      client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
  
      commandsArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
  
      table.addRow(command.data.name, "");
    });
  
    client.application.commands.set(commandsArray);
  
    return console.log(table.toString(), "\nCommands Loaded");
  }
  
  module.exports = { loadCommands };
```

File Loader

```
const { glob } = require('glob');
const path = require("path")

async function deleteCachedFile(file) {
    const filePath = path.resolve(file);
    if(require.cache[filePath]){
        delete require.cache[filePath];
    }
}

async function loadFiles(dirName){
    try{
        const files = await glob(path.join(process.cwd(), dirName, "**/*.js").replace(/\\/g, "/"));
        const jsFiles = files.filter(file => path.extname(file) === '.js')
        await Promise.all(jsFiles.map(deleteCachedFile));
        return jsFiles;
    } catch (error)
    {
        console.error(`Error loading files from directory ${dirName}: ${error}`);
    }
}

module.exports = { loadFiles }
```

I've tried console logging my slash and my index but nothing comes up.

Comment: Is this your entire codebase? Do other commands work?

Comment: @Liz This should be my entire commands/slash-commands code, i was pretty tired when i typed this so sorry for being vague.